# Reliable multicasting in Java

Tags: java, multicast

What are modern approaches for Reliable multicasting in Java world?

Searching the Web, I've came up with JGroups and JRMS. JGroups seem to be an overkill in my situation (I want to have a set of identical nodes which cooperate together and make them able to join this group by notifying every existing node). JRMS looks like being already dead.

I was unable to find any particular implementation of PGM protocol for Java.

Comment: The most common approach to sending data reliably to many hosts is to use TCP. With 40 GigE and 56 Gbit infiniband networks, multicast adds undesirable complexity for many solutions.  There are still good solutions for reliable multi-cast but I see technology improvements making it less useful.

Comment: why do you say that jgroups seems like "overkill"?

Comment: @jtahlborn: While I need to simply multicast using class D IP-addresses, it creates some clusters using configuration files, plus managing group memebership. I am not very familiar with JGroups, maybe I should investigate it deeper.

Comment: @Dimitry - yes, there really isn't anything simple about reliable multicast.  jgroups is possibly a little daunting at first glance, but in terms of runtime overhead, i don't think it's "overkill".  it can certainly do a lot, but it's not a huge package to use even for something as "simple" as group membership (especially if you want to keep track of live nodes, etc).

Comment: is JRMS still alive? The web site does not exist anymore.

Comment: @Azi, yes, it seems to be outdated...

Comment: JRMS was never a JavaSoft supported product, just a piece of research thrown over the wall. The latest download I have of it is dated 2001.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a jmdns which implements Zeroconf (Apple Bonjour) in pure Java.

Very useful if you just want to know who else is out there, and let them know about you.

http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast says it supports messaging, amongst other things (distributed maps etc)

https://hazelcast.org/

It is used as library in other distributed Java applications such as OrientDB, Apache Camel, and has plugins for Java Application Servers, such as Tomcat Session Replication.