# best way to keep clients updated in LAN - Java networking

Tags: java, networking, udp, multicast, lan

I'm working on a multi-client application that will connect with a server in the LAN.

Every client can send a command that changes the status of the server.
This 'ServerStatus', as I will call it, is an object with some values.

Now if the ServerStatus changes, all clients should know about it immediatly.
My idea was to work like this:

Server sends a multicast to all listening clients with a versionNumber of the ServerStatus every second. So if a new client joins the multicast group, he will see if his versionNumber is the same.
If not, the client will ask the current version of ServerStatus via UDP.

When a client sends a command that changes the ServerStatus,
the server will send his current (and new) ServerStatus to the same multicast group,
while in another thread, the versionnumber of ServerStatus is still shared every second.

Do you guys think this is a good way to deal with this?
Or will this cause too much problems,... etc

Comment: UDP multicast (if you have if, i.e. it's available) it's a good way to go. 1second is not "immediately", so the client just multicast a request for update and the server (or even peers can) update the newly joined one. You may need to to deal w/ lost (or out of order) UDP packets. There are a lot of frameworks to achieve that - jgroups, akka to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if the new ServerStatus fails to reach the clients? In my opinion you should not use UDP when sending the new status to the clients, but a reliable protocol. So if you intend to use multicast on this you will have to get a [reliable multicast protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861518/reliable-multicasting-in-java).

---

On the other hand, you may prefer client synchronization with the server:

- Every time a client enters the network it asks the server its *statusid* (if not the same, the server sends him ServerStatus) and the client also registers for new status change events. (TCP)
- When leaving, the client could send a UNREGISTER message (UDP).
- Each time ServerStatus changes, the server sends the new ServerStatus to each registered client. On receiving the new Serverstatus the client would send an ack-like to the server.(TCP)
- If the ack was not received by the server, the client in question would be unregistered (because it would mean the client had left the network without unregistering - by error).

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your idea sounds good to me 
I would suggest you dig more into principals of "[group communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_communication_system)", and look at frameworks such as [jGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/), I know that JBoss Cache uses it to distrubte data among its nodes. 
Maybe for reliability clients should also query the server once in X seconds, to see they they ave the correct version number, 
or at least perform this when they are started / recover from crash.